# PHP check if array contains multiple values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this fetched from a database:

```
[0] => Array (
    [permission_id] => 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [permission_id] => 2
    )
```

I would like to check if this array contains multiple values with a function. For example:

```
function checkIfArrayContains($array)
{
    ...
}

$array = array(1, 2);
checkIfArrayContains($array); //Should return true

$array = array(2);
checkIfArrayContains($array); //Should return true

$array = array(1, 2, 3);
checkIfArrayContains($array); //Should return false
```

How could this be achieved using PHP?

Comment: So basically it gives `false` if you're testing an array that has a value not present in the first one?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only getting one column from the database, and you use PDO, I would suggest you use the fetch mode `FETCH::COLUMN`, to gain an array that looks like

```php
$arr = [1, 2];
```

Then you can simply use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check for the value

Comment: How do you propose `in_array` to be used for something like `in_array([2], [1, 2])`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```php
$dbPermissions = [
    ['permission_id' => 1],
    ['permission_id' => 2],
];

function hasSufficientPermissions(array $dbPermissions, array $permissions): bool
{
    $dbPermissionValues = array_column($dbPermissions, 'permission_id');
    return empty(array_diff($permissions, $dbPermissionValues));
}

var_dump(hasSufficientPermissions($dbPermissions, [1, 2]));
var_dump(hasSufficientPermissions($dbPermissions, [2]));
var_dump(hasSufficientPermissions($dbPermissions, [1, 2, 3]));
```

This will output:

```
true
true
false
```

How it works:

- [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) reduces your database array to `[1, 2]`
- [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff) finds values in the first array supplied that are not present in the second array supplied
- if a difference exists, then `false` should be returned - this is where we utilize `empty`